# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'enqueueSnackbar'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, notistack

I have a Jest unit test that is testing an error from a mocked API call to ensure that the error message is displayed on the page. In my actual file, I'm using `notistack` to display the error messages. I've not displayed the full API request because I don't think it's relevant so in short, it is the following:

**myComponent.js**:

```
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

const myComponent = props => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()

  //make an API call to an endpoint
  ...
  if (response.ok) enqueueSnackbar("API Success", { variant: "success" });
  else enqueueSnackbar("API Failed", { variant: "error" });
}
```

As a result of this, I am testing the above on my unit test. Again, I won't paste the whole unit test because I don't think it's relevant, but something similar to:

**myComponent.test.js**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

test("testing error message on API call", async () => {
  // mock the API call to return a 500 <- this works fine

  render(<myComponent />)

  // ensure that the error message is displayed in the screen
  expect(screen.queryByText(/API Failed/)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Doing the above, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'enqueueSnackbar' of '(0 ,
> _notistack.useSnackbar)(...)' as it is undefined

If I simply include something like the following, `enqueueSnackbar()` will be defined but the test still fails because the message is `null`.

```
const mockEnqueue = jest.fn();

jest.mock('notistack', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('notistack'),
  useSnackbar: () => {
    return {
      enqueueSnackbar: mockEnqueue
    };
  }
}));
```

However, I don't even want to mock the snackbar because I want to test the actual display message for each specific scenario (there are multiple).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrapping the `render()` within my unit test with a `SnackbarProvider` resolved the issue.

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack"
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

test("testing error message on API call", async () => {
  /* mock the API call to return a 500 <- this works fine */

  render(
    <SnackbarProvider>
      <myComponent />
    </SnackbarProvider>
  )

  /* ensure that the error message is displayed in the screen */
  expect(screen.queryByText(/API Failed/)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```